# Confusion in Definition of a complete ordered field

Tags: general-topology

> A linearly ordered field *F* is called complete if every non-empty
>   sub-collection *T* of *F* that has an upper bound also has a least
>   upper bound.

$\underline{\text{In my words:}}$ every subset *T* of *F* has more than one element which are greater than all the elements of T

but then how this is possible as one of the subsets of F will have greatest element of all

Let $F=\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \} $ and $T=\{4, 5, 6\}$ then $6$ of T satisfies $6\leq 6$ with $6$ of $F$ and that makes $6$ of $F$ as the upper bound of $T$ but there is no element in $T$ greater than $6$ that makes $6$ as the least upper bound.

Comment: Can you clarify your argument? I can't really understand your rephrasing or your question.

Comment: @PatrickStevens, pls see example added

Comment: I don't see what your example has to do with any of this. The $F$ in the example is not an ordered field.

Comment: The "in your words" part seems to have little or no relation to the definition you started with.

Comment: This has nothing to do with fields per se. You should go back to ordered sets, upper bounds, and least upper bounds. What you tell "in your words" doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

> every subset $T$ of $F$ has more than one element which are greater than all the elements of $T$

It's not true that every subset $S$ contains an element $u$ which satisfies $u \geq s, \forall s \in S$. For example, consider $[0,1)$ in the prototypical ordered field $\mathbb{R}$.

> but then how this is possible as one of the subsets of $F$ will have greatest element of all

Indeed, the standard model of $\mathbb{R}$ contains no point at infinity. Based on my reading of your argument, I think the key thing you should remember is that the definition you quoted asserts the existence of a least upper bound for subsets *that already have an upper bound*, so you wouldn't be able to apply it to, say, all of $\mathbb{R}$ to produce a point at infinity.